# Trying to get count of votes in SQL based on ID

Tags: sql

Table structures:

**Solution_Votes**:

- ID int
- SolutionID string
- Vote int

**Solution**:

- ID int
- Solution
- VotesUp
- VotesDown

Code:

```
SELECT 
    *, 
    (SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN voteUp = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
     FROM Solutions_Votes) AS VoteCountUp,
    (SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN voteDown = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
     FROM Solutions_Votes) AS VoteCountDown
FROM 
    Solution
```

When I run this query it gives me the count on each row for `voteUpCount` and `voteDownCount`. I need the count to be based on the solution ID so that each solution has its count of up votes and down votes. If anybody can help it would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Only use relevant tags.  You have enough reputation that you should know this.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me out with that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use conditional aggregation.  In your case this is simple:

```
select sv.solutionid,
       sum(case when sv.voteUp = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as VoteCountUp,
       sum(case when sv.voteDown = 0 then 1 else 0 end) as VoteCountDown
from solutions_votes sv
group by sv.solutionid;
```

You only need the `solutions` table if some solutions have no votes and you want to include them.

EDIT:

You would include `solutions` in various way.  Here is one:

```
select s.*, ss.VoteCountUp, ss.VoteCountDown
from solutions s left join
     (select sv.solutionid,
             sum(case when sv.voteUp = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as VoteCountUp,
             sum(case when sv.voteDown = 0 then 1 else 0 end) as VoteCountDown
      from solutions_votes sv
      group by sv.solutionid
     ) ss
     on s.solutionid = ss.solutionid;
```

Comment: I am displaying data from the solutions table but I don't have the count for the voteUp and voteDown so I was trying to get that count by adding it up from the Solution_vote table

Comment: @Rethabile . . . I see that you code does do that.  I was responding to:  "I need the count to be based on the solution ID".  In any case, the simplest way is a `left join` to a subquery.

Comment: I was not even considering a join because I was thinking my reference table solved the need for me to use joins because the data I needed was present but its nice to see a join implemented in this solution.